# Is there an assignment operator equivalent in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In php, c, or java if I need to add to a count I simply do a `$value += 1;`

I'm looking for a similar operation in an sql server query.

## Background

I have a table that tracks some statistics with simplified columns (id1, id2, TheCount) primary key (id1,id2)

I know id1, id2, and a "modifier" value that could be 1, 0, or -1. I would like a query that allows me to update the count column with the modifier.

## Example

In theory this query would look something like:

`Update TheCounts SET TheCount += :modifier WHERE id1 = :id1 AND id2 = :id2`

Where the `:...` values are the variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: `update thecounts set thecount = thecount + :modifier where ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update TheCounts 
   SET TheCount = TheCount + @modifier 
WHERE id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2
```

But if modifier can be 0 you don't want to change it at all. Then you should check if before, f.e. with `If..Else` if it's in a stored-procedure or where you execute this.

Alternatively you could do it in the `WHERE`:

```
WHERE @modifier <> 0 AND id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2
```

Comment: Wow that was a lot easier than I expected it to be. I feel like I should have been able to figure that out on my own. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can also use += in SQL 2012 and above. So something like "`set thecount += @modifier`"